# Problema con manejo de imágenes en php (@move_uploaded_file)

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

hola buena tarde tengo un problema para el manejo de imágenes. Tengo un formulario para registrar un usuario que es el siguente:

```
<form id="frmregi" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>NOMBRE</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="nombre" id="nombre">
  <label>USUARIO</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="usuario" id="usuario">
  <label >CONTRASEÑA</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" name="pwd" id="pwd">
  <label >IMG</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control input-sm" name="imge" id="imge">
  <p></p>
  <span class="btn btn-primary" id="btnres">REGISTRARSE</span>
  <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">INICIAR SESION</a>
</form>
```

que por medio de ajax en jquery lo mando a un archivo php el codigo es el siguente:

```
$('#btnres').click(function(){
        vacios=validarfrmvacio('frmregi');
        if(vacios > 0){
            Swal.fire('Tienes campos vacíos')
            return false;
        }
        var frm= new FormData(document.getElementById('frmregi'));
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            dataType: "html",
            data:frm,
            url:"/alma2/procesos/log/registro.php",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'REGISTRADO CON EXITO',
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
                        
                    }).then((result) => {
                        /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                            window.location="/alma2/index.php";
                        } 
                    })
                       
                }else{
                    Swal.fire('Error al registrar'+r);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

y en mi archivo php tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
require_once "../../clases/usuarios.php";
$carpetaDestino="/alma2/img/user/";
 # si hay algun archivo que subir
if(isset($_FILES["imge"]) && $_FILES["imge"]["name"][0]){
    # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
    # si es un formato de imagen
    if($_FILES["imge"]["type"]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["imge"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["imge"]["type"]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["imge"]["type"]=="image/png"){
        # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
        if(file_exists($carpetaDestino) || @mkdir($carpetaDestino,0777,true)){
            $origen=$_FILES["imge"]["tmp_name"];
            $destino=$carpetaDestino.$_FILES["imge"]["name"];
            # movemos el archivo
            if(@move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino)){
                //echo "<br>".$_FILES["imge"]["name"]." movido correctamente";
            echo '<pre>', print_r($origen), print_r($destino);
                $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
                $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
                $contraseña=$_POST['pwd'];
                $urlFile=$carpetaDestino.$_FILES["imge"]['name'];
                $user= new usuarios();
                 //echo $user->insertadmin($nombre,$usuario,$contraseña,$urlFile);
            }else{
                echo "<br>No se ha podido mover el imge: ".$_FILES["imge"]["name"];
            }

        }else{
             echo "<br>No se ha podido crear la carpeta: ".$carpetaDestino;
         }
        
    }else{
         echo "<br>".$_FILES["imge"]["name"]." - NO es imagen jpg, png o gif";
     }
}else{
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $contraseña=$_POST['pwd'];
    $carpetaDestino="/alma2/img/user/sinimg.jpg";
    $urlFile=$carpetaDestino;
    $user= new usuarios();
    echo $user->insertadmin($nombre,$usuario,$contraseña,$urlFile);
}

?>
```

todo se inserta cuando el usuario no coloca una imagen en el 'input file' pero cuando agrega una imagen esta no se mueve a la carpeta ya estuve debueguenado y en la alerta me dice que se a movido correctamente pero veo en la carpeta y el archivo no esta. Les muestro el esquema de mi proyecto en donde pueden ver que la carpeta para mover los archivos existe.
[image: maquetacion de proyecto]

en consola al momento de imprimir `echo '<pre>', print_r($origen), print_r($destino);` me manda lo siguiente: C:\Windows\Temp\phpBBEE.tmp1/alma2/img/user/paletin2.png1

espero me puedan ayudar buena tarde

Answer (score 0):

Deberías poner una barra para separar la carpeta del nombre del archivo.

```php
$carpetaDestino="/alma2/img/user";
// ...
$destino=$carpetaDestino.$_FILES["imge"]["name"];
// El resultado de concatenar esas variables sería algo así: "/alma2/img/userNombreDelArchivo.png"

$destino = $carpetaDestino . '/' . $_FILES["imge"]["name"]; // Manera correcta
$destino = $carpetaDestino . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES["imge"]["name"]; // O también así

// Resultado: "/alma2/img/user/NombreDelArchivo.png"
```

**Actualización**

Estás usando rutas [relativas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_relativa) en la función [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file). La función está guardando las imágenes teniendo en cuenta la carpeta donde se encuentra el script que lo ejecuta. Te recomiendo que uses rutas absolutas.

Comment: Hola una disculpa por la demora he colocado la diagonal como mencionas y el problema persiste

Comment: @Gomaru Te lanza algún error? Deberías quitar el `@` que está antes de la función `move_uploaded_file` para que te lance un error si es que lo hay.

Comment: hola acabo de quitar el @ como mocionas en mi alerta me sigue diciendo que al archivo se movió de forma correcta

Comment: @Gomaru probá poniendo la barra al final de la variable `$carpetaDestino` así: `$carpetaDestino="/alma2/img/user/";`. Y también podrías agregar esta línea a tu código: `echo '<pre>', print_r($origen), print_r($destino);`. Agregalo justo después de `if(@move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino)){` el resultado agregalo a tu publicación **editando tu pregunta**.

Comment: listo ya la edite analizando al momento de imprimir en la imagen agrega un 1 a la imagen que desconozco de que sea

Comment: @Gomaru entonces lo está *"guardando"* bien, en principio. Si entra en el `if` es porque `move_uploaded_file` está funcionando correctamente. Y lo hace en la ruta relativa, osea en la carpeta donde está el script que se está ejecutando. Si tu script está en, por ejemplo, `C:\ProyectosWeb\alma2\src\MiScriptDondeGuardoLaImagen.php` la función lo va a guardar en `C:\ProyectosWeb\alma2\src\img\user\paletin2.png`. Te recomiendo usar rutas absolutas: `$carpetaDestino="C:\TuRuta\etc..";`

Comment: muchas gracias revise en el disco y la carpeta y las imágenes de prueba se encuentran ahí cambiare las rutas a forma absoluta muchas gracias buen día

Comment: @Gomaru La barra que separa las carpetas en Windows es \ no /. En windows es diferente que en Linux. Te recomiendo que aprendas sobre eso. Y el `1` que te aparece al usar print_r es por la función, no te hagas problema por ese uno.